# Kendo UI Mobile With Google Adsense

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, adsense

I'm trying to add a Ads into my App. I have placed the JavaScript in the correct places. The problem is that when I click to go to a page that contains the ad, only the ad shows up on the page. all the content is gone and there is only a white screen with the ad. The app won't let me hit back either so I have to restart the app. Does anyone have any clue why this might be happening?

Here is a sample of where I'm placing my code. I can place it anywhere on the page and get the same result as placing it in the footer. The other part of the Adsense code is in the Head.

```
<div data-role="layout" data-id="child-page" data-platform="android">
        <div data-role="footer">
            <script type="text/javascript"
                src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js">
            </script>
        </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. I had to put the script in the main body, not inside a div. To format it I added an ID to the script tag and then used CSS to alight the ad correctly on the screen.